# Mean of probability weights adjusting for informative censoring

Tags: survival, censoring, weights

A reviewer of a paper is giving me a hard time about presenting figures which show that my time-varying probability weights have a mean of 1 across observed timepoints. My weights (unstabilized) estimate 1 / (Probability of remaining uncensored) to account for informative censoring in an survival analysis of two treatments.

I understand why stabilized treatment weights have a mean of 1 (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2652882/). But weights for informative censoring are a different animal, right? the weighted risk set over time includes those who didn't experience the event, so even if the mean of the *stabilized* weights were 1 at baseline, it will change over time if the two groups have a different likelihood of events due to treatment effect.

Can anyone correct my thinking here?